# C#: check if file is Valid file path (not exist)

Tags: c#

I have simple `TextBox` when the user can insert `File path`.

Now I want to validate if this `File path` is valid for example:

```
c:\blabla --> this valid

c:  \blabla --> this Not valid
```

I have this function:

```
public static bool ValidateFilePath(string path)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = null;
    try
    {
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
    }

    catch (ArgumentException) { }
    catch (PathTooLongException) { }
    catch (NotSupportedException) { }
    if (fileInfo is null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

But this return `True` all the time.

Any suggestion or maybe ready `c#` method that can verify this ?

Comment: [`File.Exists(path)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I mention that i want to check if file is Valid file path not exist, this file should create but i want to verify that the path is valid\

Comment: You'd likely have to Regex to make sure the path has the proper syntax for a file path.